# Is Mongoose save async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

New to mongoose & node.

I can't figure out if mongoose document.save method is async.  I'm assuming that it is, since it works even when not connected.  Is there a way to tell when the document is actually saved (callback)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yep, it's async. You can use the 'error' parameter to see if there was an error during saving.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save